# NSFetchRequest query returns nil after setting one to many relationship

Tags: objective-c, core-data, nspredicate, nsfetchrequest, magicalrecord

I have two `NSManagedObject` subclasses, `Book` and `Category`. The two are related by one-to-many relationship.

On `Book` side, it has relationship `categories` connected to `Category`. Inversely `Category` connected to `Book` via `books`.

My app setup is to download the data from my server every time the app opened. The downloaded data will be traversed and save inside the app. In my app, I use [Magical Record](https://github.com/magicalpanda/MagicalRecord) to interact with CoreData.

`Category` data will first be downloaded and later saved from JSON format:

```
{
    "categories" : [
        {
            "id" : 1,
            "name" : "Fiction"
        },
        {
            "id" : 2,
            "name" : "Non-fiction"
        }
    ]
}
```

There has been no problem on saving `Category`. While later on the app lifecycle `Book` data will be saved from JSON format as following:

```
{
    "books" : [
        {
            "id" : 1,
            "name" : "Fiction 1",
            "category_id" : 1
        },
        {
            "id" : 2,
            "name" : "Fiction 2",
            "category_id" : 2
        }
    ]
}
```

The problem arises when I want to assign `Book` relation to `Category`. My code to assign the relationship:

```
for (NSDictionary *bookInfo in jsonObject[@"books"]) {
    Book *book = [Book createEntity];
    book.identifier = bookInfo[@"id"];
    book.name = bookInfo[@"name"];

    Category *category = [Category findFirstByAttribute:@"identifier" withValue:bookInfo[@"category_id"]];

    book.category = category;

    [[NSManagedObjectContext contextForCurrentThread] saveNestedContexts];
}
```

On the first loop, the bookObject was saved successfully. But on the second loop and next, the `Category` cannot be queried anymore. It returns nil, despite the `identifier` is the same.

I did perform check on all the `Category` via `[Category findAll]` and traversed all the records and found that the `Category` with the same id still exist on the second and next loop.

The question is why is the `findFirstByAttribute:withValue:` failed to retrieve `Category` on the second loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed this problem by updating [MagicalRecord](https://github.com/magicalpanda/MagicalRecord) to the latest version (2.1).

And then I modified the way my `NSManagedObject` saving method from `saveNestedContexts` to newly added `saveUsingCurrentThreadContextWithBlockAndWait`.

Comment: I just discovered that `saveUsingCurrentThreadContextWithBlockAndWait` worked on older iOS 5 devices where `saveWithBlockAndWait` was crashing every time. Thanks for the tip, @Willy.